# Clojure: how to get an element of a vector in another vector

Tags: vector, clojure, maps

I am very new to Clojure and am having difficulties understanding the operations of vectors/lists/maps. I am trying to print out the names of all the customers in data, but I cannot figure out how. Please help.

```
(def data
"1|John Smith|123 Here Street|456-4567
2|Sue Jones|43 Rose Court Street|345-7867
3|Fan Yuhong|165 Happy Lane|345-4533")

(defn test
[]
  (let [lines       (str/split-lines data)
        line-vecs-1 (mapv #(str/split % #"\|" ) lines)]
       (for [x line-vector-c] (print (line-vector-c 1))
       )
  )
)
```

gives me:

```
 [2 Sue Jones 43 Rose Court Street 345-7867][2 Sue Jones 43 Rose Court Street 
 345-7867][2 Sue Jones 43 Rose Court Street 345-7867]
```

what I want:

```
"John Smith"
"Sue Jones"
"Fang Yuhong"
```

Comment: Have you looked over all the other similar questions? It seems a lot of you are in the same class or something with the same homework. Click the Clojure tag, and look over the questions, as this has basically been answered a few times already.

Comment: `line-vector-c` is not defined. Also, `for` is lazy, and not recommended for side effects like printing. Use `doseq` instead.

Comment: In general, it is best to think of data as living in Clojure data structures, in this case a vector or sequence of maps. The problem then divides into two: 1. getting the data into such a form and 2. deriving and putting out the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've got so far (slightly rewritten) is:

```
(mapv (fn [l]
        (str/split l #"\|"))
      (str/split-lines data))
```

`(str/split-lines data)` splits the lines into a sequence of strings:

```
["1|John Smith|123 Here Street|456-4567"
 "2|Sue Jones|43 Rose Court Street|345-7867"
 "3|Fan Yuhong|165 Happy Lane|345-4533"]
```

`(mapv #(str/split % #"\|") lines)` splits each line into tuples of strings:

```
[["1" "John Smith" "123 Here Street" "456-4567"] 
 ["2" "Sue Jones" "43 Rose Court Street" "345-7867"]
 ["3" "Fan Yuhong" "165 Happy Lane" "345-4533"]]
```

Now you want to transform each tuple of strings into just the 2nd element of each tuple. There are a couple of functions you could use for that: `get` or `nth` (both are zero-based).

For example:

```
(mapv (fn [l]
        (get (str/split l #"\|")
             1))
      (str/split-lines data))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of names using

```
(def names
  (sequence
    (comp
      (map #(str/split % #"\|"))
      (map second))
    (str/split-lines data)))
```

Then print each name with

```
(doseq [n names]
  (println n))
```

I often use `sequence` and composed transducers to explore data, as it's convenient for building up transformations one step at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can split each line and get the second column like this

```
(defn test [xs]
    (->> (str/split-lines xs)       ;split lines
         (map #(str/split % #"\|")) ;get columns
         (map second)))             ;only the second element of each line
```

and print the result

```
(map println (test data))
```

or better using *doseq* for printing only

```
(doseq [n (test data)]
  (println n))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using RegEx:

```clj
(map second (re-seq #"\|(.*?)\|" data))
```

returns:

```clj
("John Smith" "Sue Jones" "Fan Yuhong")
```

### Explaining:

#### re-seq

We ask `re-seq` to find at each line the first content between a pair of `|`. The `?` in the regex means we want a non greedy search.

```clj
(re-seq #"\|(.*?)\|" data)
```

returns:

```clj
(["|John Smith|" "John Smith"] ["|Sue Jones|" "Sue Jones"] ["|Fan Yuhong|" "Fan Yuhong"])
```

#### map

Finally, we use `map second` to visit each element of the list and get only the second string of the vector.